# Scrolling priority in the bottom sheet fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-sheet

So I have a nested scroll view inside the bottom sheet fragment and the default behavior is to expand the bottom sheet to the top of the screen first and then scroll the long text inside the nested scroll view. how can change the default behavior to scroll the long text inside nested scroll view first and disable draggable when the user tries to scroll the long text and allow the user to draggable manual from the top like the youtube app

Default behavior

https://s10.gifyu.com/images/default.gif

Expected behavior

https://s10.gifyu.com/images/expected.gif

**Note** : I can't upload the preview to stack overflow because of the 2MB upload limit

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/close_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@null"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="Title text"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/close_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/title_tv">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/short_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Short text"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/example_btn"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Example Button"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/short_tv" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/long_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="@string/long_text"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/example_btn" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

ExampleBottomSheet.kt

```
class ExampleBottomSheet : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using BottomSheetDialogFragment which is less "flexible". Try to redesign your activity/fragment to use CoordinatorLayout and embed layout with bottom sheet behavior there.

```
<!-- this should be the new root of your main activity/fragment -->
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  ...>

    <!-- Root LinearLayout from your bottom_sheet.xml, just add style and layout_behavior property -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
        style="?attr/bottomSheetStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

        ...
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

then you can create instance of BottomSheetBehavior in your activity/class using `BottomSheetBehavior.from(View)`. This will gain you access to control state of your bottom sheet.

Here you can read more about standard bottom sheet: https://material.io/components/sheets-bottom/android#standard-bottom-sheet

And here you have nice comparison between standard and modal (BottomSheetDialogFragment) bottom sheets: https://medium.com/over-engineering/hands-on-with-material-components-for-android-bottom-sheet-970c5f0f1840

Comment: `BottomSheetBehavior.from(View)` is a getter, it doesn't create any instance. Also in fragment you can obtain behavior as well by using `.from(view.parent as view)`. And I'm not sure if it helps much anyway since you can just flip a switch to have ui behave like in question.